# How to resize and make my social media buttons on my blog responsive?

Tags: html, css

I need some help. I am facing an issue with my blog template. http://www.candidopinions.in/

I have tried very hard to make it responsive to all mobile devices, however when the screen size is reduced to anything less than 321 pixels (like for iPhone 4 (320 x 480), I am facing problem with the social media buttons (just below My blog's name Candid Opinions) in the header and with the pagination buttons at the bottom. These two groups of buttons stack up. I am not very proficient with CSS but still I tried my best to resolve the issue but couldn't.

Can someone help me in making these buttons responsive?

```css
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
.post-outer {width:100%;}
#search, #search-form {width:auto;}
#search-form { font-size: 14px; }
#breakingnews,.date-time {display:none}
#header,#header .description,#header h1,#header p,#header a{text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}
#header-wrapper{margin:0 auto;}
#wrapper,#menu,#menutop,#rapih,.tab{width:100%;margin:0 auto;}
#social_networks{bottom:20px;display:block;float:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}
#social_networks ul {display:block;text-align:center;height:30px;margin:0 auto;}
#social_networks li{display:inline-block;float:none;width:30px;height:30px;
opacity:0.5;background-position:left top;border:3px solid #ffffff;border-radius:50%;transition:All 0.4s ease;}
#social_networks li:hover{opacity:1;background-position:left -30px;border:3px solid #e291fd;box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}


#social_networks li a{display:inline-block;width:30px;height:30px;}
#social_networks li a span{display:none;}

#blog-pager{
font-size:13px;
line-height:20px;
padding:2em 0;
}
.showpageNum a,.showpage a,.showpagePoint{
margin-top:11px;
margin-bottom:16px;
margin-left:4px;
font-size:13px;
padding:6px 10px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:240px){
.post-outer {width:100%;}
#search, #search-form {width:auto;}
#breakingnews,.date-time,#menutop {display:none}
#header,#header .description,#header h1,#header p,#header a{text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}
#header-wrapper{margin:0 auto;}
#wrapper,#menu,#rapih,.tab{width:100%;margin:0 auto;}
#social_networks ul{bottom:20px;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Social icons** At the moment, it looks as though your social buttons are behaving responsively, flowing onto multiple lines when there's no longer room for them to fit on one line in the viewport. This only seems to kick in below 330px, and is fairly standard behaviour, but if you'd like to keep them all on one line then you could use a media query to control the width and height of the list items:

```
@media screen and (max-width: whatever) {
    selector {
       width: Xpx;
       height: Xpx;
       padding/margin: (to control vertical/horizontal spacing)
}
```

Some quick thoughts on this: 
 1. Bear in mind that this can make the logos very small and hard to click on on mobile, so it might be better for accessibility/usability to just have them flow onto multiple lines but retain their size, as they do now, particularly for a potentially v small group of users on devices <330px.
 2. Consider having a go with iconfonts to display your Facebook, Twitter, etc, logos. Using background images as you do currently makes resizing very difficult, whereas with iconfonts it's much simpler and will allow for cleaner HTML. More on those here: https://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/

**Pagination units**  For me, on Chrome, these are overflowing the page on mobile widths. Perhaps switch to the same usage of li tags rather than spans for each page number - this will give you cleaner, semantically correct code and you can then just apply display: inline-block to allow them to behave responsively. Same tips as above apply from there.